# SpringBoot graphQL getting Invalid Syntax for nested Object

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, nested

I am using GraphQL in my SpringBoot app. While the CRUD operations are running for single objects, I am facing the issue of Invalid Syntax for nested objects. Please find the code below and suggest.

**graphql**

```
type Book {
    isn: Int
    title: String
    author: String
    publishedDate: String
    publisher: Publisher!
}


input PublisherInput {
    pId : Int
    publisherName: String
    address: String
}

type Mutation {
    addBook(isn: Int, title: String, author: String, publishedDate: String, publisherInput: PublisherInput) : Book
}
```

**Service**

```
    public DataFetcher<Book> addBook() {
        return dataFetchingEnvironment -> {
            PublisherInput publisherInput = objectMapper.convertValue(dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("publisherInput"), PublisherInput.class);
            Publisher publisher = modelMapper.map(publisherInput, Publisher.class);
            publisherRepository.save(publisher);
            Book book = new Book(dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("isn"), dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("title"), dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("author"), dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("publishedDate"), publisher);
            bookRepository.save(book);
            return book;
        };
    }
```

**Request**

```
mutation {
    addBook(
        isn: 100,
        title : "Book Test",
        author : "aabb",
        publishedDate : "12-11-2012",
        publisherInput(
            pId: 2002,
            publisherName: "test",
            address: "aassd"
        )
    )
    {
        isn
        title
    }
}
```

Getting the below error

**Response**

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid Syntax",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 7,
                    "column": 16,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think that you should use syntax `someArgumentName : {}` rather than `someArgumentName()` when specifying the mutation argument which the type is the input object.

So change to the following should solve the problem :

```
mutation {
    addBook(
        isn: 100,
        title : "Book Test",
        author : "aabb",
        publishedDate : "12-11-2012",
        publisherInput : { 
            pId: 2002 ,
            publisherName: "test",
            address: "aassd"
        }
    )
    {
        isn
        title
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error ......."message": "Exception while fetching data (/addBook) : Unrecognized field \"pId\" (class com.example.SpringBootGraphQL2.entity.PublisherInput), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: \"pid\", \"address\", \"publisherName\"])\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.example.SpringBootGraphQL2.entity.PublisherInput[\"pId\"])",

Comment: So it means my suggestion can really solve your question which no more syntax error anymore. Now your latest exception is another problem which is not related to this question. Suggest to raise another question and provide more details about it. And also consider to vote up my answer or mark it as the accepted answer if you find my answer is helpful to you as i spend a lot of time to help you for free. thanks.

Comment: But that doesn't fully solve the issue

Comment: that belongs to another issue which does not match your questions now. so ask another question and provide more details about it